# Remove item from list incrementally working but the list keep rebuilding on each scene change

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a manager that loads random scenes by index# from a List of possible indexes. Once the scene gets loaded I want to remove that item from the list to eliminate the same scene from getting loaded again. Once the manager has gone through all of the scenes I then call `DoInitSceneIndexList()` again to create a new list that is populated with scenes and the process starts all over again. Everything works here except one thing. Whenever I switch scenes the list is getting rebuilt again and it's starting from a full list rather than being decremented by one each time. Where am I making the error that rebuilds the the list each time a scene gets loaded? thank you!

**ForestGameManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ForestGameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ForestGameManager fgm = null; // create singleton

    ForestSceneTimer forestSceneTimer;

    [Header("Network Prefab")]
    public GameObject serverNetworkManagerPrefab;

    [Header("Forest Game Manager")]
    private int fgmIndex;
    private int firstForestSceneIndexNumber;
    private int lastForestSceneIndexNumber;

    [Header("Forest Scenes")]
    [TextArea(1,1)]
    public string forestSceneNotes = "Please place all Forest Scenes after Forest Loader scene";
    public int numberOfForestScenes;
    public float sceneCountdownLength;
    private List<int> forestSceneIndexes;
    private int randomSceneIndex;
    private bool initSceneList = true;
    private int currentSceneIndex;

    [Header("Forest Animal Management")]
    public int maxAnimalCount = 4;
    public List<ForestAnimal> forestAnimals;

    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoInitForestGameManager());
        StartCoroutine(DoInitServerNetworking());

        fgmIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        firstForestSceneIndexNumber = fgmIndex + 1;

        Debug.Log("firstForestSceneIndexNumber Index is : " + firstForestSceneIndexNumber);

        forestSceneTimer = GetComponent<ForestSceneTimer>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        forestAnimals = new List<ForestAnimal>();
        forestSceneIndexes = new List<int>();
        lastForestSceneIndexNumber = ((firstForestSceneIndexNumber + numberOfForestScenes) - 1);

        if (initSceneList)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DoInitSceneIndexList());
            StartCoroutine(DoGetRandomScene());
        }

        Debug.Log("There are " + numberOfForestScenes + " forest scenes in MasterLoader.");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Destroy oldest animal gameobject based on maxAnimalCount
        if (forestAnimals.Count >= maxAnimalCount)
        {
            GameObject toDestroy = forestAnimals[0].forestAnimalGO;
            forestAnimals.RemoveAt(0);
            Destroy(toDestroy);
        }

        if (currentSceneIndex >= firstForestSceneIndexNumber && currentSceneIndex <= lastForestSceneIndexNumber)
        {
            // If all forest scenes have been used, re-initialize scene name list and pick the next random scene
            if (forestSceneIndexes.Count == 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(DoInitSceneIndexList());
                StartCoroutine(DoGetRandomScene());

                Debug.Log("Out of scenes, re-initializing scene list.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

        Debug.Log("Current scene index is : " + currentSceneIndex);

        if (currentSceneIndex >= firstForestSceneIndexNumber && currentSceneIndex <= lastForestSceneIndexNumber)
        {
            // Start scene change countdown timer
            forestSceneTimer.StartSceneCountTimer(sceneCountdownLength);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DoInitSceneIndexList()
    {
        // Initialize scene name list
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfForestScenes; i++)
        {
            forestSceneIndexes.Add(firstForestSceneIndexNumber + i);
            //Debug.Log("Scene index " + forestSceneIndexes[i].ToString() + " added to int list.");
        }
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        initSceneList = false;
    }

    private IEnumerator DoInitForestGameManager()
    {
        if (fgm == null)
            fgm = this;
        else if (fgm != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    private IEnumerator DoInitServerNetworking()
    {
        Instantiate(serverNetworkManagerPrefab);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    public void GetRandomScene()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoGetRandomScene());
    }

    private IEnumerator DoGetRandomScene()
    {
        //Debug.Log("First forest scene index : " + firstForestSceneIndexNumber);
        //Debug.Log("Last forest scene index : " + lastForestSceneIndexNumber);

        // Get scene name from random pick
        randomSceneIndex = Random.Range(firstForestSceneIndexNumber, lastForestSceneIndexNumber);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        StartCoroutine(DoRemoveRandomSceneFromList());

        // Load selected scene
        StartCoroutine(DoLoadScene(randomSceneIndex, 0.0f));

        Debug.Log("randomSceneIndex is " + randomSceneIndex);

        for (int i = 0; i < forestSceneIndexes.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Scene " + forestSceneIndexes[i].ToString() + " is still left in the list");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DoRemoveRandomSceneFromList()
    {
        // Remove selected scene from list
        forestSceneIndexes.Remove(randomSceneIndex);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    private IEnumerator DoLoadScene(int sceneIndex, float loadDelay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(loadDelay);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

**ForestSceneTimer.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ForestSceneTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ForestSceneTimer fst = null; // create singleton

    private IEnumerator _counter;

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitRestartTimer();
    }

    void InitRestartTimer()
    {
        if (fst == null)
            fst = this;
        else if (fst != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public void StartSceneCountTimer(float length)
    {
        //ForestGameManager.fgm.DestroyRestartTimer = false;
        Debug.Log("Scene Timer Started");
        _counter = RunTimer(length); // create new reference to counter, resets countdown to countdownLength
        StartCoroutine(_counter);
    }

    IEnumerator RunTimer(float seconds)
    {
        float s = seconds;
        while (s > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            //if (RestartDialogBoxInstance != null)
                //_restartDialogCountdownTextTarget.text = s.ToString();
            s -= 1;

            if (s <= 0)
                ForestGameManager.fgm.GetRandomScene();

            Debug.Log(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your List from being rebuild each time, you have to do 2 things.

### DontDestroyOnLoad

Add the following call to your Awake() method of the *ForestGameManager*.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
```

This way your object wont be destroyed on SceneChange anymore. And is kept until you destroy it or end the game.

### Do not initialize 2 times

1. Add a private bool _isInitialized to your GameManager
2. Use the bool to check if your GameManager is allready initialized

   ```
   private void Start() {
     if (!this._isInitialized) {
       forestAnimals = new List<ForestAnimal>();
       forestSceneIndexes = new List<int>();
       lastForestSceneIndexNumber = ((firstForestSceneIndexNumber + numberOfForestScenes) - 1);

       if (initSceneList) {
         StartCoroutine(DoInitSceneIndexList());
         StartCoroutine(DoGetRandomScene());
       }

       Debug.Log("There are " + numberOfForestScenes + " forest scenes in MasterLoader.");
       this._isInitialized = true;
     } else {
       this.forestAnimals.Clear(); //I assume you can clear the list on scene change
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: made these changes but it's still repeating scenes, it's not removing the last scene loaded from the list, anything else that might still be missing?